# Cast from size_t to int, or iterate with size_t?

Tags: c++

Is it better to cast the iterator condition right operand from `size_t` to `int`, or iterate potentially past the maximum value of `int`? Is the answer implementation specific?

```
int a;
for (size_t i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++)
{
    if (some_func((int)i))
    {
        a = (int)i;
    }
}

int a;
for (int i = 0; i < (int)vect.size(); i++)
{
    if (some_func(i))
    {
        a = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: I take it you mean size_t everywhere your question says type_t? If so, please edit it.

Comment: Note that `size_t` and `int` aren't the same type, even on a 32-bit system.  `size_t` is unsigned while `int` is signed.  This can be a significant item.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I almost always use the first variation, because I find that about 80% of the time, I discover that `some_func` should probably also take a size_t.

If in fact `some_func` takes a signed int, you need to be aware of what happens when vect gets bigger than `INT_MAX`.  If the solution isn't obvious in your situation (it usually isn't), you can at least replace `some_func((int)i)` with `some_func(numeric_cast<int>(i))` (see Boost.org for one implementation of numeric_cast).  This has the virtue of throwing an exception when vect grows bigger than you've planned on, rather than silently wrapping around to negative values.

Comment: I like the idea of an exception being thrown in this case, since it eliminates any really weird behaviour... Then again, it'd be a massive amount of hassle, considering it's probably never going to go over `INT_MAX`.

Comment: @Nick: Why do you think that adding a include and using a different cast (and a proper one, FTM -- C-style casts are never proper) is too much hassle.

Comment: A function should "do what you want".  A function that "does what you want until some undocumented limit is crossed and then does something else" is what is commonly termed a "landmine".  Leaving landmines in your code is always a bad idea for anything other than a homework problem.

Answer (score 3):

I'd just leave it as a `size_t`, since there's not a good reason not to do so. What do you mean by "or iterate potentially up to the maximum value of type_t"? You're only iterating up to the value of `vect.size()`.

Answer (score 1):

For most compilers, it won't make any difference. On 32 bit systems, it's obvious, but even on 64 bit systems, both variables will probably be stored in a 64-bit register and pushed on the stack as a 64-bit value.

If the compiler stores **int** values as 32 bit values on the stack, the first function should be more efficient in terms of CPU-cycles.

But the difference is negligible (although the second function "looks" cleaner)

Comment: Thanks, yes I was thinking the 2nd looks cleaner since there's less casting. Agreed?